# How do I position my table to be under each other in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am having problem making table 11 to be under table 10 within laTex. For my tables I am been using `[!]` and `[h]` to make my tables display under each other but now once I got to table 11 it will not go under table 10

I have tried to do a few method which was using float package and place in packages but it seem that no changes are being done.

I've also had this problem before because at first I was using `[h]` and all the tables were going under each other but then it stopped working so I used `[!]` but now that is not working

So this is table 10

```
\begin{table}[!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Test\#        & 10                                                                                                        
\\ \hline
Content       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Testing emails to be registered 
when signing up\\ to be a lender.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Input         & Signing up and lending out a product.                                                                     
\\ \hline
Pass Criteria & Signing up with the ability to lend out products.                                                         
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

table 11 is the same but it won't go under table 10 instead laTex places it somewhere random

```
\begin{table}[!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Test\#        & 11                                                                                                                              
\\ \hline
Content       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Testing the billing information 
input to see \\ if it works.\end{tabular}                            \\ 
\hline
Input         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The user rents out a product 
and check if\\ billing information is appearing correctly.\end{tabular} \\ 
\hline
Pass Criteria & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Billing information appears 
when checkout is\\ completed.\end{tabular}                               
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there any way I could properly place table 11 to be directly under table 10 instead of placing it somewhere random like the image is displaying below. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: `!` on it's own is no valid floating specifier, you must combine it with a conventional one, e.g. `[h!]` (however I would suggest another approach, if the tables should follow each other, place them in the same floating environment)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach, if the tables should directly follow each other, place them in the same floating environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Test\#        & 10                                                                                                        
\\ \hline
Content       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Testing emails to be registered 
when signing up\\ to be a lender.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Input         & Signing up and lending out a product.                                                                     
\\ \hline
Pass Criteria & Signing up with the ability to lend out products.                                                         
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Test\#        & 11                                                                                                                              
\\ \hline
Content       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Testing the billing information 
input to see \\ if it works.\end{tabular}                            \\ 
\hline
Input         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The user rents out a product 
and check if\\ billing information is appearing correctly.\end{tabular} \\ 
\hline
Pass Criteria & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Billing information appears 
when checkout is\\ completed.\end{tabular}                               
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```